# Has anyone used DEX agent in TOSCA and what are the benefits?

Tags: tosca

Anyone know the benefits/drawbacks of using DEX agent in tosca compared to the execution list.

From my research, it seems that DEX agent has better performance as it is running the testing on multiple VMs.

Comment: https://www.tricentis.com/products/automate-continuous-testing-tosca/distributed-test-execution/

Answer (score 0):

Execution list is pushed on to the Dex execution queue. So I assume you mean disadvantages/benefits of running on DEX vs local.

When you execute your tests, Tosca takes control of your mouse and keyboard, so it can interact with the system under test. Consequently, users can't work on this machine for the duration of the test run. And if you have large test sets, it simply takes too long to run all of them on one machine.

With Tosca Distributed Execution, you can distribute your tests across all available computing resources, such as computers in your network, virtual machines. This speeds up large test runs and leaves user machines unblocked.